# SWT_AWT.new_Frame: JComboBox never lose focus when window is moved

Tags: java, focus, swt, awt

I do have a strange focus problem when using a JComboBox inside an embedded frame.

i created a new Shell like

```
shell = new Shell(display.getActiveShell(), SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

The shell i use to create an embedded frame like

```
    Composite contentComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED);
    contentComposite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(contentComposite);
    rootPanel = new Panel();
    rootPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(rootPanel);
```

I added a JComboBox (with 2 elements) to the rootPanel.
When i select the ComboBox for opening the drop down menue, i can drag and drop the shell window, without losing the focus in the combo box.

The drop down menue is still in the same place on the screen, also when the shell window is moving to another screen area. The drop down menue is not shown below the combo box anymore.

i tried to add a focus listener to some of the components, but the focus is not lost on the combo box and not gained on the shell.

So how can i hide the popup of the combo box, when the shell is moved or gets the focus.

Comment: `SWT_AWT.new_Frame`  Mixing SWT with AWT?  `JComboBox`  So now it is SWT/AWT/Swing?!?  Does SWT not have an equivalent of the Swing combo box?  It does not surprise me that a mix of all 3 ends in disaster.

Comment: thats the challenge. Everything else is less fun. But you are right, i can try to use 2 UI features first.

Comment: *"thats the challenge"* Challenge?  I don't think you understand the details of this mixing.  For e.g. It is only in Java 1.7 that Oracle has enabled functionality to  reliably mix **Swing & AWT.**  *"AWT has no ComboBox, as far as i see."*  In AWT it is called a [`Choice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html) component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) described in his comment, that 3 different UI libraries are not the best choice, i started to try the AWT [Choice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html) class.

These class is losing the focus, when the shell window is selected.

So it seems, that swing can not be used so easily in embedded AWT objects, but the reason i dont see yet.

Comment: See [Mixing heavy and light components](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/) for more details.